# Boost::signals2 - Passing a signal slot as argument

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

I'm using boost::signals2 to create a class that uses a signal to run an event under a specific condition. This class has a method that is called: **RegisterCallback**.

This function should take a parameter of the slot type that the signal uses (which is of **void** return type with a **double** as the only arg).

However, I'm not quite sure how I should define that argument in the method signature, as the source file for the signal1 class is quite unreadable for me.

So I basically want to do this:

```
myTimer(interval);
myTimer.RegisterCallback(&aCallbackFunction);
```

Here is the member signal:

```
boost::signals2::signal<void (double)> m_signal;
```

... and here is the register method that I need (uncomplete)

```
   /**
    * Register a callback function that will be called when the timer interval elapses.
    */
    void RegisterCallback(const boost::signals2::signal1<???????> &slot)
    {
        m_signal.connect(slot);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the boost::function and boost::bind library I think.

```
typedef booost::signals2::signal(void (double)>::slot_type CallbackSlot
void RegisterCallback(CallbackSlot slot)
{
    m_signal.connect(slot);
}

// ...

class MyClass {void handler(double);}

// ...

RegisterCallback(boost::bind(MyClass::handler, this, _1));
```

I propose that you also read the boost::function and boost::bind documentation to use signals2 in a good way. This example code is not tested but contains all the stuff needed to solve your problem.

Comment: that solution worked really well. Reading a bit more about it, but worked wonders. Thanks